# If & Else statement in webflow inside of a view-state

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

I've the following `view-state`:

```
<view-state id="editbestellung" view="eap/orderedit.xhtml"
    model="flowScope.entity">
    <transition on="save" to="eaporderlist" bind="true">
        <evaluate
            expression="eapBestellungDelegate.save(flowScope.entity,currentUser.name)" />
    </transition>
</view-state>
```

No elsewhere I set a `flowScope.isToDo` on **true**.
Now I need to check if this flowScope is true. If it is, the `transition` should redirect `to="eapordertodolist"` and if it is false, it should go `to="eaporderlist"`.
But I only know how to set the if-statement like that:

```
<if test="testingMethod()" then="view-state when true" else="view-state when false" />
```

So how can I implement the if-statement inside of the view-state above and do the needed actions?

Comment: when are you setting `flowScope.isToDo` on true? in the save-method?

Comment: No earlier. But the variable stays the whole lifetime of the flow...

Comment: and you wnat to check AFTER the save method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Decision-States](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/spring-webflow-reference.html#decision-state)

> Use the decision-state element as an alternative to the action-state to make a routing decision using a convenient if/else syntax. The example below shows the moreAnswersNeeded state above now implemented as a decision state instead of an action-state

Your `editbestellung`-state will look like this (notice that i changed the `to`):

```
<view-state id="editbestellung" view="eap/orderedit.xhtml"
    model="flowScope.entity">
    <transition on="save" to="eaporderdecision" bind="true">
        <evaluate
            expression="eapBestellungDelegate.save(flowScope.entity,currentUser.name)" />
    </transition>
</view-state>
```

Then you add the decision-state:

```
<decision-state id="eaporderdecision">
    <if test="flowScope.isToDo" then="eapordertodolist" else="eaporderlist" />
</decision-state>
```

Comment: Exactly this if-statement i use...? The problem is, that i already have a transition on statement. I need to change the `to=` part of this transition. And i don't know how to do that

Comment: click on the link. there is a good explanaition. you will need an extra state to prcess the decision

Comment: @PhilippSander Just a comprehension question: is it necessary to create a method? Is the `flowScope`, which contains true / false, not enough? Can't test it currently...

Comment: honestly: i'm not sure!

Comment: @user2413035 could you try that?

Comment: You do not need to create a method. You can directly test a value that is in the scope.

Comment: i edited the answer. do i need `(` and `)` around `flowScope.isToDo`?

Comment: No you won't need it :) Thanks a lot. It works perfect. Sorry i answer now, had school yesterday :)